# E: unable to locate package idle3 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, idle, idle-python

I have ubuntu 18.04 and python3.6.5. I want to install idle but was unable to.
What I tried was,

```
python3
```

it displays ( I hide the date and time)

```
python3.6.5 (default, date, time)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Then I update the cache

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It worked smoothly.
After this, I tried to install idle3

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package idle3
```

I am not sure what went wrong. I also tried this

```
lsb_release -a
```

which gave me

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I also searched it here [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=idle3&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all).

And then the next command I wrote was

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

and then updated it. But when typed it again, it gave me the same.

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package idle3
```

Can someone help? I am quite new to CS and Ubuntu SE, so really sorry if this question wasn't written well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idle3 package in Ubuntu has been renamed to three different packages: idle-python3.6, idle-python3.7 and idle-python3.8. Please install the idle3 package that matches your system's Python 3.x version. Python 3.6 is the default Python 3.x version in Ubuntu 18.04, and the command to install idle3 for this version in Ubuntu 18.04 is `sudo apt install idle-python3.6`. To show the system's Python 3.x version open the terminal and type:

```
python3
```

Comment: Actually, we realised it was some problem with PC. It wasn't updating. Now it works! Thanks a lot for answering!